# Is there no way to get RealPath from URI for Video which supports all API's in Android?

Tags: android

After a lot of search, I have still not found a solution which would return the `realPath` of a video in the device, when the `URI` is passed to it.

Why are there so many complexities on this ? Is there no way that this can be achieved and the code could run in all the `API` versions of android, at least above 16 in my case.

Can anyone say why this problem is occurring and whether there is any solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who says there is a real path? Videos don't have to be local: they could be streamed to your app by another app.

Comment: I am speaking about videos which are present in the device. I don't care about streaming videos.